# Unable to parse .nt file with rdflib

Tags: python, rdflib, n-triples

My `my_data.nt` file looks like this:

```
<bob> <name> "Robert" .
<bob> <knows> <amy> .
```

I am using this code to parse it:

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()
g.parse("my_data.nt", format="nt")

for ele in g:
    print(ele)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/ntriples.py", line 140, in parse
    self.parseline()
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/ntriples.py", line 189, in parseline
    subject = self.subject()
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/ntriples.py", line 216, in subject
    subj = self.uriref() or self.nodeid()
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/ntriples.py", line 235, in uriref
    uri = self.eat(r_uriref).group(1)
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/ntriples.py", line 210, in eat
    raise ParseError("Failed to eat %s at %s" % (pattern.pattern, self.line))
rdflib.plugins.parsers.ntriples.ParseError: Failed to eat <([^:]+:[^\s"<>]+)> at <bob> <name> "Robert" .

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_query.py", line 5, in <module>
    g.parse("my_data.nt", format="nt")
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1043, in parse
    parser.parse(source, self, **args)
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/nt.py", line 26, in parse
    parser.parse(f)
  File "/Users/x/MyVirtualEnvs/new_python3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/ntriples.py", line 142, in parse
    raise ParseError("Invalid line: %r" % self.line)
rdflib.plugins.parsers.ntriples.ParseError: Invalid line: '<bob> <name> "Robert" .'
```

What am I missing?

When I try contents of `my_data.nt` on [easyrdf](http://www.easyrdf.org/converter) it appears to be perfectly fine.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/2013/N-TriplesReports/index.html#test_nt-syntax-bad-uri-06

Comment: Use `format="turtle"`. Optiolally, add `@base...` to your data.

Comment: Thank You @StanislavKralin, so the reason is that `<bob>` (and so on) is not a valid `URIRef`? The solution is to use proper `URIRef`, for example `<http://example/bob>`.

Comment: They are relative URIs. Only absolute URIs are allowed in N-Triples. Use absolute URIs or declare format as Turtle.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, got it. Makes sense. Thank You.

Comment: You completely answered my question, so fell free to post an answer.